# How to assign number to each value in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary-comprehension

I am comparatively new to python and data science and I was working with a CSV file which looks something like:

```
value1, value2
value3
value4...
```

Thing is, I want to assign a unique number to each of these values in the csv file such that the unique number acts as the key and the item in the CSV acts as the value like in a dictionary.

I tried using pandas but if possible, I wanted to know how I can solve this without using any libraries.

The desired output should be something like this:

```
{
"value1": 1,
"value2": 2,
"value3": 3,
.
.
.
and so on..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was just about to talk about pandas before I saw that you wanted to do it in vanilla Python. I'd do it with pandas personally, but here you go:

You can read in lines from a file, split them by delimiter (','), and then get your word tokens.

```
master_dict = {}
counter = 1
with open("your_csv.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split(',') # you may or may not want to add a call to .strip() as well
        for word in words:
            master_dict[counter] = word
            counter += 1
```

Comment: Thanks brother, this was exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: @Rocky4 if above answer was correct and what you expected, please mark the answer as accepted. This will allow other readers to avoid answered questions. Thank you.

Comment: @tchainzzz What if any value gets repeated in the CSV file, I don't want to assign another key to it, Rather the already assigned key should again be given for that repeating value. how do I do it?